# Difference between JScrollBar and JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

What are the differences between **JScrollBar** and **JScrollPane**?

Comment: I think you should be a little bit more specific in your question.

Comment: which part of their respective java doc didn't you understand?

Comment: It would be quicker for you to type your question in Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This image is self-explainatory

[image]

> The JViewport provides a window, or "viewport" onto a data source --
>   for example, a text file. That data source is the "scrollable client"
>   (aka data model) displayed by the JViewport view. A **JScrollPane
>   basically consists of JScrollBars, a JViewport, and the wiring between
>   them, as shown in the diagram at right**.

[JScrollPane api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)